# Get quote item collection by using quote item id in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, collection, model, quote, quoteitem

I get the `quote_item_id` like this:

```
$orderItems = $order->getAllItems();
foreach($orderItems as $orderItem){
    $qouteItemId = $orderItem->getQuoteItemId();
}
```

I need to load quote item collection using `quote_item_id`.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: do you need quote item Id?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
private $quoteItemFactory;
private $itemResourceModel;
public function __construct(
  .....
  \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\ItemFactory $quoteItemFactory,
  \Magento\Quote\Model\ResourceModel\Quote\Item $itemResourceModel
  ......
) {
   ....
   $this->quoteItemFactory = $quoteItemFactory;
   $this->itemResourceModel = $itemResourceModel
   ...
}
```

and in one of the methods you can do this:

```
$itemId = your id here
$quoteItem = $this->quoteItemFactory->create();
$this->itemResourceModel->load($quoteItem, $itemId);
```

Comment: I have try above code for load Quote Item by item id but i am getting following error. "Fatal Error: 'Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Magento\\Quote\\Model\\ResourceModel\\Quote\\Item::getProductId()

Answer (score 4):

I want to improve the accepted answer.
Unfortunately the repo tied to QuoteItem model `\Magento\Quote\Api\CartItemRepositoryInterface` doesn't have a `get()` method.
So, to load a quote item entity from db we have 2 options:

- use the model factory `\Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory` (like the
  accepted answer)
- use the collection factory
  `\Magento\Quote\Model\ResourceModel\Quote\Item\CollectionFactory`

On my magento 2.3.5 the issue with the accepted answer is that `$quoteItem->getOptions()` is **empty**!
To load quote item with options filled, i need to use the collection like this:

```
public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Quote\Model\ResourceModel\Quote\Item\CollectionFactory $quoteItemCollectionFactory
    ...
) {
    ...
    $this->quoteItemCollectionFactory = $quoteItemCollectionFactory;
    ...
}

// load the quote item
$quoteItemCollection = $this->quoteItemCollectionFactory->create();
$quoteItem           = $quoteItemCollection
    ->addFieldToSelect('*')
    ->addFieldToFilter('item_id', [quote_item_id])
    ->getFirstItem();

// retrieve the quote item options
$quoteItemOptions = $quoteItem->getOptions();
```

Comment: Thanks, Worked perfectly for me on 2.4.3.

Answer (score 1):

you can load the quote id by injecting the instance of `\Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory`

```
protected $quoteFactory;
public function __construct(
  .....
  \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory $quoteFactory
  ......
){
   $this->quoteFactory = $quoteFactory;
}

$quote = $this->quoteFactory->create()->load($quoteId);
$items = $quote->getAllItems();
```

Comment: i need to load quote item using quote item id not load quote by quote id

Comment: Yes you can get items by $items = $quote->getAllItems();

Answer (score -1):

you can inject in your class an instance of `\Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory.`

```
protected $quoteFactory;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory $quoteFactory,
    ....
) {
    ....
    $this->quoteFactory = $quoteFactory;
    ....
}
```

Then you can use:

```
$quote = $this->quoteFactory->create()->load($quoteId);
```

Comment: i need to load quote item using quote item id not load quote by quote id

Answer (score -1):

First load the quote object

```
 $quote = $this->quoteRepository->getActive($cartId);
  foreach ($quote->getItems() as $item) {    
         $quoteItem = $quote->getItemById($item->getItemId()); 
  }
```