# Magento2: How to get quote item through item id?

Tags: magento2, quoteitem, cart-items

I want to get quote item through the item id on the guest page.

**Got the null value**

```
<?php
namespace Codism\Csr\Block\Index;

class Approveitem extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template {

protected $_coreRegistry;


public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry,
    \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\ItemFactory $quoteItemFactory,
    \Magento\Quote\Model\ResourceModel\Quote\Item $itemResourceModel
)
{
   $this->_coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;
   $this->quoteItemFactory = $quoteItemFactory;
   $this->itemResourceModel = $itemResourceModel;
   parent::__construct($context);
}

public function getCustomerCartDetails(){
    $itemId = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('itemId');

    $quoteItem = $this->quoteItemFactory->create();
    $item = $this->itemResourceModel->load($quoteItem, $itemId);

    return $item;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get by following code.

```
public function __construct(
  \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\ItemFactory $quoteItemFactory,
  \Magento\Quote\Model\ResourceModel\Quote\Item $itemResourceModel
) {
   $this->quoteItemFactory = $quoteItemFactory;
   $this->itemResourceModel = $itemResourceModel

}
```

Below is code for your logic

```
$itemId = your item id
$quoteItem = $this->quoteItemFactory->create();
$this->itemResourceModel->load($quoteItem, $itemId);
```

This code is given [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/232269/get-quote-item-collection-by-using-quote-item-id-in-magento-2) in answer.

Comment: Can we get quote item without customer login?

Comment: It is not working. Got the null value. I want to to get cart item collection from the database without customer login.

Answer (score 0):

```
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Session;

public function __construct(
        ...
        Session $session
        ...
    ) {
        ...
        $this->_session = $session;
        ...
    }

public function yourCustomFunction()
{
    $items = $this->_session->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
}
```

Comment: I want to get quote item details on the guest page not after login.

Comment: the above code is to get quote items data from session. so it is working on all magento page.

Comment: Got the  Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getAllVisibleItems()

Answer (score 0):

Using getItemById from Quote Model

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/Quote/Model/Quote.php#L1478

```
/**
 * Retrieve item model object by item identifier
 *
 * @param   int $itemId
 * @return  \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item|false
 */
public function getItemById($itemId)
{
    foreach ($this->getItemsCollection() as $item) {
        if ($item->getId() == $itemId) {
            return $item;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

If you have quote

```
$quoteItem = $quote->getItemById($itemId);
```

For example

```
<?php

namespace Codism\Csr\Block\Index;

class Approveitem extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Backend\Model\Session\Quote
     */
    protected $_sessionQuote;

    protected $_coreRegistry;


    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry,
        \Magento\Backend\Model\Session\Quote $sessionQuote
    )
    {
        $this->_coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;
        $this->_sessionQuote = $sessionQuote;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function getCustomerCartDetails()
    {
        $itemId = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('itemId');

        /** @var $quote \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote */
        $quote = $this->_sessionQuote->getQuote();

        if($itemId) {
            $quoteItem = $quote->getItemById(intval($itemId));

            return $quoteItem;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to get customer cart item without customer login

Comment: Using `Magento\Backend\Model\Session\Quote`
`$quote = $quoteSession->getQuote();`
To get current quote, then you could get the $quoteItem without caring whether customers logged in or not

Comment: Can you update your post?

Comment: Ok, I will check and update you.

Comment: The code is not working. I have debugged ***$quoteItem*** got the message evaluate expression

Comment: @MasudShaikh Check your $itemId whether it's exist

Comment: Yes, Item id is exist  in database.

Comment: Can i create custom item collection factory in my custom module?